# Failed to resolve issue of addition in Javascript everytime variable value is concatenated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

Here is my code i m successfully getting dynamic values from code but failed to do addition like this

```
var abc = 0;
var someValue = 5;
abc += someValue;
var  grandTotalProposalCost = 0;
```

**CODE:**

```
var totalSum = parseFloat(summField.total_mat_sale +summField.total_labour_sale).toFixed(2);
grandTotalProposalCost += totalSum;
alert("summary line 96::::"+grandTotalProposalCost);
```

Everytime i am getting dynamic values from database in `summField.total_mat_sale,summField.total_labour_sale`    and i want to get total sum.But failed to do so.........

in alert i am getting `summary line 96::::1250.266648.828596.25`
Here

`totalSum = 1250.26` is the value which i am getting first time then
2nd time `totalSum = 6648.82` and
third time `totalSum= 8596.25`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your values are concatenated as string. Try using `parseFloat` to parse your value before adding them.

```
grandTotalProposalCost += parseFloat(totalSum);
```

Hope this helps